# Adobe Illustrator - importing DXF files from QGIS3

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to import .DXF files into Illustrator which are produced by QGIS3, when creating the QGIS3 dxf output there are many options to choose encoding types of the .DXF file.

All options that I have tried so far have resulted the file loading but not viewable, as the items seem to be scaled incorrectly. So, my question is:

What .DXF encoding formats does Adobe Illustrator accept/work best with?/ Where would I be able to find this information?

Comment: It's common issue faced before; hope this can help you :) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241162/exporting-adobe-illustrator-ai-file-layer-from-qgis

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need access to all the QGIS layers (in which case you're doing multiple exports anyway) you're probably better off using SVG or PDF out and going from a page composer mapping to control scale prior to your Illustrator work - that's what I do.